# Understanding how AFNetworking APIs are used in block callbacks in iOS

Tags: ios, block, afnetworking

In the following method to reload a UITableView, when does the "response" variable get set? Apparently, an http request must have been executed by some AFNetworking method and the "response" variable set, before the

NSLog(@"%@", response)

statement.

The basic issue is that I do not understand how the block :

```
^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
    NSLog(@"%@", response);
    self.tweets = [Tweet tweetsWithArray:response];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

actually works.

Can someone explain?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That is a block (as you've identified) and is passed into the method as a block of code to execute at some point.

The method will expect a block of code that expects an `AFFTTPRequestOperation` and an `id response` that it will call when it seems fit (usually after an async operation).

That method basically says: "If you give me a chunk of code that takes this specific input, I'll call it when I'm ready"

Imagine I'm a dog washer: I put out an advert saying that if you give me your dog I'll shampoo him. You're a busy person with specific requirements.

So I say: book the dog in for a shampoo - is there anything you want me to do once I've finished washing him?

You tell me you want him brushed and delivered you your aunties house. I can now store those instructions and once the dog is washed, I can carry them out *without delegating the work to you.*